# Obtener horas totales de un rango de fechas que cumplan intervalos de tiempo en php

Tags: php, date, datetime, time

¿cómo se puede hacer en PHP para obtener el número de horas de un rango de fechas que cumplen un intervalo de tiempo? Por ejemplo, teniendo el rango de fechas:

```
SUBIDA = 2017-01-02 01:00 - BAJADA = 2017-01-02 22:00
```

Y sabiendo que los intervalos son:

```
DE 00:00 a 06:00 y DE 22:00 a 23:59
```

Se debe encontrar el total de horas del rango que aplican entre esos intervalos. Para el caso del ejemplo, con los datos proporcionados se debería obtener:

```
DE 00:00 a 06:00 -> 5 horas
DE 22:00 a 23:59 -> 2 horas
```

Estoy utilizando por el momento este código:

```
if ($h1<$h2)
                 {
                     $res2=MIN($h2,'23:59:59')-MAX($h1,'22:00:00');
                     $res1=MIN($h2,'06:00:00')-MAX($h1,'00:00:00');
                 }
                 else
                 {
                     $res2=MAX(0,('23:59:59')-($h1))+MAX(0,$h2-('22:00:00'));
                     $res1=MAX(0,('06:00:00')-($h1))+MAX(0,$h2-'00:000:00');
                 }
```

Donde, $h1=subida en formato 'H:i:s' y $h2=bajada en formato 'H:i:s'.

El código me funciona pero no muy preciso, ya que me devuelve a veces 1 ó 2 horas menos en algun intervalo.

¿Alguien tiene una forma mejor de hacerlo? Gracias de antemano.

Reginaldo Bray

Comment: Ya entendí, no había comprendido lo que necesitas, por ejemplo un rango de días digamos  2017-01-01 00:00 a 2017-01-07 00:00, han pasado 7 días, y ha cumplido 7 veces los los periodos de 00:00 a 06:00 y 22:00 a 23:59 significa que (6+1)*7 = 49 horas trascurridas en ese periodo, estoy el lo correcto ?

Comment: Exacto. No estoy seguro si el intervalo 22:00 a 23:59 = 1 (para mí es 2 pues 23:59 es 24:00, aunque no se pueda colocar así y 24-22 = 2). Pero sí, esa es la idea. el ejemplo que coloqué al principio asume que el rango de subida y bajada es el mismo día, para facilitar. Gracias.

Comment: ¿Alguien tiene una idea? Gracias.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Después de tanto probar, he llegado a lo siguiente que cumple con lo que necesitaba:

```
$hora_inicio = $ini->format("H:i");
                  $hora_fin = $fin->format("H:i");
                  //INTERVALO DE 00:00 a 06:00
                  if(($hora_inicio<='06:00') && ($hora_fin>'06:00') )
                  {

                      $intervalo1 = clone $ini;
                      $intervalo1 = $intervalo1->setTime(06,00);
                      $diferencia1 = ($intervalo1->diff($ini));
                      $diferencia1 = ($diferencia1->format('%d') * 24) + $diferencia1->format('%H') + ($diferencia1->format('%i') / 60);

                  }
                  else if(($hora_inicio<='06:00') && ($hora_fin<='06:00') )
                  {   $diferencia1 = ($fin->diff($ini));
                      $diferencia1 = ($diferencia1->format('%d') * 24) + $diferencia1->format('%H') + ($diferencia1->format('%i') / 60);
                  }
                  else if ($hora_inicio>'06:00')
                  {
                      $diferencia1 = 0;
                  }

                  //INTERVALO 22:01 a 23:59

                  if (($hora_inicio>=$horares.':01') && ($hora_fin<='23:59') )
                  {

                      $diferencia2 = ($ini->diff($fin));
                      $diferencia2 = ($diferencia2->format('%d') * 24) + $diferencia2->format('%H') + ($diferencia2->format('%i') / 60);
                  }
                  else if (($hora_inicio<$horares.':01') && ($hora_fin>=$horares.':01'))
                  {

                      $intervalo2 = clone $ini;
                      $intervalo2 = $intervalo2->setTime($horares,01);
                      $diferencia2 = ($intervalo2->diff($fin));
                      $diferencia2 = ($diferencia2->format('%d') * 24) + $diferencia2->format('%H') + ($diferencia2->format('%i') / 60);

                  }
                  else if ($hora_fin<$horares.':01')
                  {

                      $diferencia2=0;
                  }

                   return ($diferencia1+$diferencia2);
```

Hice varias pruebas aleatorias y me ha funcionado. El único requerimiento es que la fecha de inicio y la fecha final (Y-m-d) deben ser iguales lo cual, para lo que lo necesito, está bien. Si alguien puede mejorarlo me cuentan.